# network byte order to host byte order in java

Tags: java, io, byte, socket.io

I'm stuck with interpreting a response from a C server to my java application. Hoping that the C server is responding to my java in BIG_ENDIAN format, my question is how would I convert the response to an `Integer`. I'm pasting the response I got from the the C server and wondering how would I do "be64toh" function in java.

Response from the C server -

> ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^A^A^B^@^@^@^N^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<80>^@^@^@^@^@^@^BÃ^@^@^@^AYour
>   request is successfully registered with us and is under
>   processing.^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Â¨Ã½f^@^@^@^@^@mX@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^N^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H

I'm not sure how to interpret the non readable bytes and when converted to hexadecimal most of them are `null` but few of them are filled with data just like the `^H`, `^A` etc.. Can you please help me find a solution for this one.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a java.nio.SocketChannel to read from, you can use a ByteBuffer to do the conversion:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
int bytesRead = socketChannel.read(readBuffer);
readBuffer.flip();
```

Now you can read your data out of the buffer, e.g.:

```
int someInt = readBuffer.getInt();
long someLong = readBuffer.getLong();
```

Comment: +1 BTW: ByteBuffer is big endian by default, but it is better to be explicit. Since the OP asks about reading 32-bit integers I would add a `getInt()` example.

Comment: Hi Erich, Thank you for the response.. I'm using Socket and DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to send and receive data to the C server application. Below is the snippet -             clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
   
   if(clientSocket!=null) 
   System.out.println("Connected to localhost on port >>"+port);
   
   os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream (clientSocket.getInputStream());

Comment: You can use `SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.connect(SocketAddress);` instead.

Comment: Ok.. I changed my java application to use SocketChannel now.. And doing just the same as in the above snippet by Eric. When I print the long variable, it just gives me a long number.. Not sure what am missing but would like to see an ASCII type of message like..                 707  Your request is successfully registered with us and is under processing. Thanks.!

Comment: You will need to read the documentation of the C server you are trying to talk to - or reverse engineer the protocol. From what you have posted, the data stream seems to contain some binary header and some mixed binary / text payload. You will need to read each element separately using the various `get...()` methods of the buffer.